# Network profile not recognizing that I have a careers profile

Tags: bug, jobs, profile-page

This is a picture from the math.stackexchange profile page. I do in fact have a Careers profile, but for some reason, my profiles on the individual stackexchange sites aren't recognizing that.
[image]